# bcoin how to get zero confirmation

Tags: zero-confirmation

I`m using a bcoin (version=v1.0.0-beta.14) and I´m trying to get information about zero confirmations of a address imported into my wallet. All I get are informations about transaction with at least 1 confirmation.

Currently I´m using testnet. Are there any differences to livenet?

My command is a rpc call with the following request body:

```
{"method":"listreceivedbyaddress", "params":["0"] }
```

As result I get 3 trx with the first having 2 confirmation, the second 2 confirmation and the third 9 confirmation

If I change "params" from 0 to 4 i only get one trx in result, which is what I do expect.

While I´m performing an additional trx I and changeing the "params" to 0 I only get any infomraiton as soon as the trx get´s it´s first confirmation.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there no way to get informed of zero confirmations?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!